# addons:add is not a heroku command

Tags: heroku

I am trying to add mongolab addon to my heroku app using CLI, but I get below message every time I use `heroku addons:add mongolab` command.

```
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
 ▸    addons:add is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant plugins:link
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

Any idea what is happening and a way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command to create a new addon and attach it to your app is [`heroku addons:create`](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab), not `heroku addons:add`:

```
heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox
```

If that still gives you a "semver" error your Heroku CLI may be broken. Try reinstalling it.

You can use `heroku addons --help` to see details about using the `heroku addons` command.

Comment: That will create a new project I assume. I already have a project but I just want to add addon to my existing project.

Comment: Even `heroku addons --help` return me this `Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
 ▸    addons is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant plugins
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.`

Comment: @null, no, it won't create a new app. It will create a new _addon_. If you have an existing addon you can use `heroku addons:attach` instead, but I don't think that's the case for you.

Comment: Even with create command i.e. `heroku addons:create mongolab:sandbox`, I am getting this `Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
 ▸    addons:create is not a heroku command.
 ▸    Perhaps you meant plugins:update
 ▸    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.`

Comment: @null, what does `heroku --help` give? What about `heroku -v`?

Comment: `heroku -v` gives this `Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
heroku-cli/6.15.11-5cba33c (darwin-x64) node-v9.3.0`

Comment: and `heroku --help` gives this `Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Refreshing plugins... !
 ▸    semver has no commands. Is this a CLI plugin?
Refreshing plugins... done
Usage: heroku COMMAND

Help topics, type heroku help TOPIC for more details:

 auth
 plugins  add/remove CLI plugins`

Comment: It looks like your `heroku` CLI is borked. Please try reinstalling it.

Comment: Reinstalling seemed to work. But account verification of heroku with CC seems to halt my testing process :(.